# Calculation of payroll date based on pay period using C#

Tags: c#

I want to calculate payroll date based on Pay Period. Pay period starts on Sunday, and runs till Saturday.
Ex:
2023-01-15 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00 (sunday - start date)
2022-01-21 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  (saturday - end date)

Given start and end dates as inputs and I want the output date (payroll date) as 2022-01-27 00:00:00.0000000 (Friday).

I need formula and  do we have any built-in function in C# to achieve this ?

Comment: sooo... just end date + 6 days?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like all you need is:

```
DateTime payRollDate = payPeriodDate.AddDays(5);
```

Comment: @pelletier Are you saying that need to add 5 days to end date and that will be the payroll date? Will this work for leap year as well?

Comment: Yes, it will work for leap years. It just adds 5 days to the date. But you have to use the DateTime type, not a string